# What is "it" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

What is "it" in the following sentence?

> He distorted the shape of a common object to make **it** harder to recognize.

Is '**it**' pronoun?
Is '**it**' formal object(= dummy object)?

Comment: it is the shape of a common object

Comment: It's a pronoun used anaphorically to refer to the noun phrase "a common object".

Answer (score 1):

*It* is a pronoun that stands in place of *common object*:

> He distorted the shape of *a common object* to make **[the common object]** harder to recognize.